# Журнал подключений к удаленному рабочему столу

Tags: windows

Как в WinXP просмотреть журнал исходящих подключений к удаленному рабочему столу, конкретно IP к которым осуществлялись подключения?

Answer (score 1):

смотрите в сторону настройки групповой политики